# Getting TypeError trying to sum the contents of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ctn =0
myfile = open("lab3.txt")
lines = myfile.readlines
for item in myfile:
        ctn += item
print(int(ctn))
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You should also drop `lines = myfile.readlines`; you're getting lucky here in that you didn't actually call `readlines`; if you had, `for item in myfile:` would yield nothing (because the `readlines()` call would have slurped the file and left the file object sitting at the end of the file with nothing to read).

Comment: Have you tried checking the type of item?

Comment: By default you read from files as string, if you want to use it as int, you will have to typecast it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

your item doesn't declare to be int on your code. try parsing it.

```
int ctn = 0
myfile = open("lab3.txt")
lines = myfile.readlines
for item in myfile:
    ctn += int(item)
print(ctn)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by 'sum the contents of a file'? Are you adding up all the numbers in a file called 'lab3.txt'?

To store the contents of a file in a variable, you can use `myfile.readlines()`. (Not `myfile.readlines`--the brackets are necessary. If you don't use brackets, that statement does not read anything.) Or use the `for` block to traverse the contents of the file one line at a time. **But not both**, as ShadowRanger's comment explains.

Let's say 'lab3.txt' contains the following lines.

```
84
236
956
31
163
538
4
861
```

To find their sum, you could do something like this.

```
ctn = 0
myfile = open('lab3.txt')
for item in myfile:
    ctn += int(item) # convert string to integer
print(ctn)
```

Here, `item` will sequentially take the (string) values of each line in the file. It gets converted to an integer and added to `ctn`.

`readlines` returns a list. (Each element of that list is a string, the strings being the lines in the file.) If you must use `readlines`, you will have to convert the elements in the list to integers.

```
myfile = open('lab3.txt')
lines = myfile.readlines()
lines_int = [int(item) for item in lines]
ctn = sum(lines_int)
print(ctn)
```

Don't forget to close the file.

```
myfile.close()
```

You won't have to bother with this `close` if you use file context. Observe how you can reduce the code to just two lines.

```
with open('lab3.txt') as myfile:
    ctn = sum([int(item) for item in myfile.readlines()])
```